# Импорт .txt файла в Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, импорт, txt

Пытаюсь импортировать текстовый файл в Jupiter Notebook через pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/bbchealth.txt', header=None)
```

Выдает следующую ошибку

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 2, saw 13
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Если вы не хотите, чтобы мы гадали на кофейной гуще, приведите фрагмент (желательно первые несколько строк) вашего текстового файла.

Comment: Причина в том, что в первой строке 11 полей, а во второй 13.  Pandas не знает в какой столбец сохранить два лишних поля.